# Linked List is Printed reverse in C

Tags: c, c99

This program scans an input and prints it using the concept of linked lists in C. The program scans for an input and stops when it encounters a '-'. The problem is that it prints the input in reverse. I don't want to implement another function that will reverse the whole thing. please help i don't know where the error is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct student {
    char name[64];
    unsigned long long student_number;
    struct student *next;
} student;

int main()
{
    student *curr_stdptr;
    student *hd_stdptr = NULL;
    int i,x,y;
    char input[70];
    char in_name[60];


    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
                    curr_stdptr = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
                    curr_stdptr->next = hd_stdptr;
                    hd_stdptr = curr_stdptr;

                    fgets(input,60,stdin);
                    for(x=0;input[x]!='-';x++)
                        hd_stdptr->name[x] = input[x];
                        hd_stdptr->name[x] = '\0';

                    }


    while(curr_stdptr!=NULL) {
    printf("%s\n",curr_stdptr->name);
    curr_stdptr=curr_stdptr->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: We don't know what the error is either as you haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: @Lee poor choice of wording on the OP's part. The problem is clearly stated: "The problem is that it prints the input in reverse". The intent is to print in the same input order.

Comment: You're asking others to read your code for you, the least you could do is indent it properly...

Answer (score 1):

```
    curr_stdptr = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
                curr_stdptr->next = hd_stdptr;
                hd_stdptr = curr_stdptr;
```

Everytime you read a new `student` you insert it at the beginning making it the new head.So the last `student` becomes the head.So you will always get the reverse order.You can insert new `students` at the end every time.This way you can maintain the order.

```
       //initialize hd_stdptr and curr_stdptr as NULL before loop
       new_stdptr = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
       new_stdptr->next=NULL;
       if(hd_stdptr!=NULL)//not the first node
       {
           curr_stdptr->next = new_stdptr;
       }
       else
       { //first node
          hd_stdptr = new_stdptr;
       }
       curr_stdptr = new_Stdptr;
```

EDIT:edited after @WhozCraig comment.

---

**Forward Chaining Pointer-to-Pointer Method**

An alternative build method for constructing a linked list in input-order is to use *forward-chaining* with a pointer to pointer. Initially, the pointer-to-pointer holds the address of the `head` pointer (which is initially `NULL`). As items are input, it always holds the address of the pointer that will receive the next node. When finished, it is terminated with the final null, thereby terminating the list

A complete example including fixing several potential problems in your code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char name[70];
    unsigned long long student_number;
    struct student *next;
} student;

int main()
{
    student *hd_stdptr = NULL, *p;
    student **pp = &hd_stdptr;

    int i,x;
    char input[70];


    for(i=0; i<6 && fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin) != NULL; ++i)
    {
        student *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate new student: ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (x=0; input[x] && input[x] != '-' && input[x] != '\n'; ++x)
            p->name[x] = input[x];
        p->name[x] = 0;

        /* save where new node belong */
        *pp = p;

        /* and advance our ptr-to-ptr to address location for next node */
        pp = &p->next;
    }
    *pp = NULL;


    for (p=hd_stdptr; p; p = p->next)
        printf("%s\n",p->name);


    /* free the list */        
    while (hd_stdptr)
    {
        p = hd_stdptr;
        hd_stdptr = p->next;
        free(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting a pointer-to-pointer eliminates the need for the continual checking of the head-set on a forward-chained linked list. Also, the second statement in both those blocks can be pulled outside of each and consolidated below.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect what I described. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    student *curr_stdptr;
    student *hd_stdptr = NULL;
    student *tail_stdptr = NULL;
    int i,x,y;
    char input[70];
    char in_name[60];


    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
                    curr_stdptr = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
                    if( i == 0)
                    {
                       tail_stdptr = hd_stdptr = curr_stdptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tail_stdptr->next = curr_stdptr;
                        tail_stdptr = curr_stdptr;
                    }

                    fgets(input,60,stdin);
                    for(x=0;input[x]!='-';x++)
                        tail_stdptr->name[x] = input[x];
                        tail_stdptr->name[x] = '\0';
                    }

    curr_stdptr = hd_stdptr;
    while(curr_stdptr!=NULL) {
    printf("%s\n",curr_stdptr->name);
    curr_stdptr=curr_stdptr->next;
    }

}
```

You can try this code, you can add another pointer `tail_stdptr` which points to the tail of the `linked list`.
For every added element, you can append it to the tail of the linked list according `tail_stdptr`.